# Angular2 - Check if a new class added to the directive with @HostListener

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a directive and I want to detect if `x` class is added to the DOM element which uses that directive. For example, let say I have a link

```
<a myLink class="">A link</a>
```

Then, `active` class is added to that element from a `javascript`

```
<a myLink class="active">A link</a>
```

I want to detect this class in MyLink directive. I tried something like

```
  @HostListener('class',['active'])
  onVisible(){
    console.log("Element active");
  }
```

But not surprisingly, it's not working. How can I do that with a `HostListener` or any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@HostListener()` is only for events.

You can use `ngDoCheck` like

```ts
export class MyClass implements DoCheck {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {
    console.log('myClass');
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
    console.log('classList: ' + this.elRef.nativeElement.classList);
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kvRIwqYhz6V99UfXaBiN?p=preview)

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html

Comment: But I think this will work only at start, how should I check for changes on these then?

Comment: I think you still need some more coffee :) You didn't change the content of `ngDoCheck`, there isn't a variable named `value` in that function :) I did the same thing from the plunker and it prints my `classlist` when the change on classes made inside of my directive. However, when I toggle the sidebar (using Sematic-UI btw) and `semantic.js` changes its classes, it doesn't detect a change and not printing anything. But I think it is another problem and I should accept this answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Right, I had the correct code in the Plunker and the incorrect commented out and put the incorrect code into the question.

Comment: I assume the problem with Semantic-UI is, that it doesn't cause Angulars  change detection to run. If Semantic-UI runs outside Angulars zone, Angular doesn't recognize that it should run change detection after code was executed. I don't know Semantic-UI or how you integrate it with Angular. If change detection isn't run, Angular doesn't call `ngDoCheck()` or any other code.

Comment: I think you're right. Semantic-UI has no integration with Angular2 yet, I am trying to integrate manually the components which I needed.

Comment: If you can initialize Semantic-UI inside Angular that should do.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Use [( )] for two way binding. Through this syntax, any changes to DOM will become available in your component

html:

```
<a myLink [(class)]="status">A link </a>
```

In your component class:

```
private status: String;
...

if (status=='active') {
   //the class is active
}else{//class is something else
}
```

**Original:**

Generally you assign the class through logic in your component. I suggest you review your approach and see if you can do something like this:

In your component class:

```
private status: String;
...

if (condition) 
this.status = "active"
else 
this.status = ""
```

html:

```
<a myLink [class]="status">A link </a>
```

hope it helps

Comment: The class is added with an external framework, I don't want to change it manually. I want to know when it's added.

Comment: Semantic-ui, bootstrap, etc. All these frameworks can manipulate DOM elements.